# CSS Grid Layout: how to make background colour span multiple cells?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

For a FreeCodeCamp assignment I am making an iOS Calculator clone in CSS Grid Layout. The JavaScript to run it is work for later; I'm now focusing on a the design.

The final result should look something like this:

[image]

```css
html {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.2fr 1fr 1.2fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(700px, auto);
}

.wrapper>div {
  padding: 0;
}

.nested-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
}

.nested-1>div {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  color: white;
}

.top-bar {
  padding-top: 0.3rem;
}

.flight-modus {
  justify-self: start;
  padding-left: 0.3rem;
}

.charge-status {
  justify-self: end;
  padding-right: 0.3rem;
}

.nested-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
  justify-items: end;
}

.nested-2>div {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 0.2rem;
  padding-right: 0.2rem;
  align-self: end;
}

.nested-3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  color: black;
  background: #ddd;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.operations {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.3rem;
}

.bg-grey {
  background: #ccc;
}

.left-cell {
  background: black;
}

.right-cell {
  background: black;
}

.calculator {
  background: #333333;
}
```

```html
<body class="">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left-cell">
    </div>

    <div class="calculator">
      <div class="nested-1 top-bar">
        <div class="flight-modus"><img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/sebv9j.png" alt="flight mode"> &nbsp;
          <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/5zqf4k.png" alt="wifi signal at full strength"></div>
        <div>10:10 am</div>
        <div class="charge-status">96% <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/30ldxtx.png" alt="battery at near full charge"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="nested-2 result">
        <div>3,658.8</div>
      </div>

      <div class="nested-3 keys">
        <div class="operations bg-grey">C</div>
        <div class="operations bg-grey">+/-</div>
        <div class="operations bg-grey">%</div>
        <div class="operations bg-grey">/</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>5</div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="right-cell">
    </div>
  </div>
```

What I did:

I have made a general grid with several nested grids. 
No.3 of these nested grids has to hold the calculator keys (digits 0-9, basic math operations, 
result, clear).

How do I set a continuous `background-color` across a certain number of `cells` e.g. darker grey, orange etc.?
Now, setting the `bg` on my individual `divs` is leaving gaps.
Next, the `cell-borders` should also get a 1px solid color, as per the example.

Having searched around on SO and in CSS Grid layout / CSS Flexbox tutorials, 
I could not find a simple solution to this obviously simple task.
Should I bring Flexbox into my Grid here?

As much as I appreciate the wonderful new dynamics Grid brings, and its compatibility with Flexbox, I am still very much new to both.

Any tips and remarks on my code structure are welcome!
Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To *fix* the borders and background of `nested-3`, you could set the background and borders using:

   ```
   background: #888;
   grid-gap: 1px;
   ```

   and for all the *children* of `nested-3` you could set background:

   ```
   .nested-3 > div {
     background: #ddd;
   }
   ```
2. Instead of `padding` on `.operations` you could add this to `nested-3 > div`:

   ```
   .nested-3 > div {/* ADDED */
     background: #ddd;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     padding: 1.3rem;
   }
   ```

   and you might have to remove `justify-items: center` and `padding: 1rem` from the `nested-3` div.

I tried out the design too - rearranged the markup like so:

```
<div class="nested-3 keys">
    <!-- MODIFIED HERE -->
    <div class="operations bg-grey">C</div>
    <div class="operations bg-grey">+/-</div>
    <div class="operations bg-grey">%</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div class="zero">0</div>
    <div>.</div>
    <div class="operations bg-grey op-right">/</div>
    <div class="op-right">x</div>
    <div class="op-right">-</div>
    <div class="op-right">+</div>
    <div class="op-right">=</div>
</div>
```

and added these styles:

```
.nested-3>.op-right {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  background: #fd8a0d;
}

.nested-3>.op-right+.op-right {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.nested-3>.op-right+.op-right+.op-right {
  grid-row-start: 3;
}

.nested-3>.op-right+.op-right+.op-right+.op-right {
  grid-row-start: 4;
}

.nested-3>.op-right+.op-right+.op-right+.op-right+.op-right {
  grid-row-start: 5;
}

.zero {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

See the snippet below:

```css
html {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.2fr 1fr 1.2fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(700px, auto);
}

.wrapper>div {
  padding: 0;
}

.nested-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
}

.nested-1>div {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  color: white;
}

.top-bar {
  padding-top: 0.3rem;
}

.flight-modus {
  justify-self: start;
  padding-left: 0.3rem;
}

.charge-status {
  justify-self: end;
  padding-right: 0.3rem;
}

.nested-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
  justify-items: end;
}

.nested-2>div {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 0.2rem;
  padding-right: 0.2rem;
  align-self: end;
}

.nested-3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  /*justify-items: center;*/
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  color: black;
  background: #888;/* CHANGED */
  grid-gap: 1px;/* ADDED */
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  /*padding: 1rem;*/
}

.nested-3>div { /* ADDED */
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1.3rem;
}

.operations {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  /*padding: 1.3rem;*/
}

.bg-grey {
  background: #ccc;
}

.left-cell {
  background: black;
}

.right-cell {
  background: black;
}

.calculator {
  background: #333333;
}

/* ADDED THESE BELOW */

.nested-3>.op-right {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  background: #fd8a0d;
}

.nested-3>.op-right+.op-right {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.nested-3>.op-right+.op-right+.op-right {
  grid-row-start: 3;
}

.nested-3>.op-right+.op-right+.op-right+.op-right {
  grid-row-start: 4;
}

.nested-3>.op-right+.op-right+.op-right+.op-right+.op-right {
  grid-row-start: 5;
}

.zero {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<body class="">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left-cell">
    </div>

    <div class="calculator">
      <div class="nested-1 top-bar">
        <div class="flight-modus"><img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/sebv9j.png" alt="flight mode"> &nbsp;
          <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/5zqf4k.png" alt="wifi signal at full strength"></div>
        <div>10:10 am</div>
        <div class="charge-status">96% <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/30ldxtx.png" alt="battery at near full charge"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="nested-2 result">
        <div>3,658.8</div>
      </div>

      <div class="nested-3 keys">
        <!-- MODIFIED HERE -->
        <div class="operations bg-grey">C</div>
        <div class="operations bg-grey">+/-</div>
        <div class="operations bg-grey">%</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div class="zero">0</div>
        <div>.</div>
        <div class="operations bg-grey op-right">/</div>
        <div class="op-right">x</div>
        <div class="op-right">-</div>
        <div class="op-right">+</div>
        <div class="op-right">=</div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="right-cell">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi kukkuz, could you explain the css class syntax `.op-right+` ? What does the `+` do? Great input thanks, Chris

Comment: `+` for **adjacent selectors** got it!

Answer (score 2):

It's very good that you try to use grid but just do it carefully (https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/03/30/should-i-use-grid-or-flexbox/). For your issue I would use the grid only for the 3 cells (left, center and right). But I have used Flexbox for your "nested-3"-box here with intent so you can try it out and play with it a bit.

```css
html{
 font-size: 20px;
}

.wrapper{
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1.2fr 1fr 1.2fr;
 grid-auto-rows: minmax(700px, auto);
}

.wrapper > div{
 padding: 0;
}

.nested-1{
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
 justify-items: center;
}
.nested-1 > div{
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.6rem;
 color: white;
}

 .top-bar{
 padding-top: 0.3rem;
 }

 .flight-modus{
  justify-self:start;
  padding-left: 0.3rem;
 }

 .charge-status{
  justify-self:end;
  padding-right: 0.3rem;
 }

.nested-2{
 display: grid;
 grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
 justify-items: end;
}
 .nested-2 > div{
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 0.2rem;
  padding-right: 0.2rem;
  align-self: end;
 }

.nested-3{
 display: flex;
 font-size: 2.2rem;
 color: black;
 background: #ddd;
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
 font-weight: lighter;
}
  .keys {
    display: flex;
  }
  
  .wrapper1 {
    flex: 1 0 75%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  .wrapper1 > div {
    flex: 1 0 25%;
    height: 94px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .wrapper1 > div.null {
    flex-basis:58%;
  }
  .wrapper2 {
    flex: 1 0 25%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: orange;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  .wrapper2 > div {
    height: 94px;
    border: 1px solid #777;
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
.bg-grey{
 background: #ccc;
}

.left-cell{
 background: black;
}
.right-cell{
 background: black;
}

.calculator{
 background: #333333;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <!-- EDIT HEAD INFO INSIDE CODEPEN PREFS -->
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
 </head>
 <body class="">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-cell">
  </div>

  <div class="calculator">
   <div class="nested-1 top-bar">
    <div class="flight-modus"><img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/sebv9j.png" alt="flight mode">
     &nbsp;
     <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/5zqf4k.png" alt="wifi signal at full strength"></div>
    <div>10:10 am</div>
    <div class="charge-status">96% <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/30ldxtx.png" alt="battery at near full charge"></div>
   </div>

   <div class="nested-2 result">
   <div>3,658.8</div>
   </div>

   <div class="nested-3 keys">
    <div class="wrapper1">
        <div>C</div>
        <div>+/-</div>
        <div>%</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
        <div>9</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>1</div>
        <div class="null">0</div>
        <div>.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="wrapper2">
        <div>/</div>
        <div>X</div>
        <div>-</div>
        <div>+</div>
        <div>=</div>
      </div>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div class="right-cell">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will help! But as I said, try to think about if it does make sense to use grid or flex for small things. Have a look at the performance, too.

Answer (score 2):

### Tile Borders

A simple way to make the black borders would be to give the container a black background color.

```
.nested-3 {
  background: black;
}
```

Then apply your foreground color to each key.

```
.nested-3 > div {
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

(Use flexbox to center the content.)

Then use the [**`grid-gap`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-gap) property to create small gutters, which will simulate borders.

```
.nested-3 {
  grid-gap: 1px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/a13L2rb0/)

```css
html {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.2fr 1fr 1.2fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(700px, auto);
}

.wrapper>div {
  padding: 0;
}

.nested-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
}

.nested-1>div {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  color: white;
}

.top-bar {
  padding-top: 0.3rem;
}

.flight-modus {
  justify-self: start;
  padding-left: 0.3rem;
}

.charge-status {
  justify-self: end;
  padding-right: 0.3rem;
}

.nested-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
  justify-items: end;
}

.nested-2>div {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 0.2rem;
  padding-right: 0.2rem;
  align-self: end;
}

.nested-3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  /* justify-items: center; */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  color: black;
  background: black;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding: 1rem;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.nested-3>* {
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.operations {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.3rem;
}

.left-cell {
  background: black;
}

.right-cell {
  background: black;
}

.calculator {
  background: #333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-cell">
  </div>

  <div class="calculator">
    <div class="nested-1 top-bar">
      <div class="flight-modus"><img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/sebv9j.png" alt="flight mode"> &nbsp;
        <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/5zqf4k.png" alt="wifi signal at full strength"></div>
      <div>10:10 am</div>
      <div class="charge-status">96% <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/30ldxtx.png" alt="battery at near full charge"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="nested-2 result">
      <div>3,658.8</div>
    </div>

    <div class="nested-3 keys">
      <div class="operations">C</div>
      <div class="operations">+/-</div>
      <div class="operations">%</div>
      <div class="operations">/</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="right-cell">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Row / Column Background Color

Standard CSS selectors can handle the task of setting background colors on rows and columns.

**Row**

```
.operations {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.3rem;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/a13L2rb0/1/)

```css
html {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.2fr 1fr 1.2fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(700px, auto);
}

.wrapper>div {
  padding: 0;
}

.nested-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
}

.nested-1>div {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  color: white;
}

.top-bar {
  padding-top: 0.3rem;
}

.flight-modus {
  justify-self: start;
  padding-left: 0.3rem;
}

.charge-status {
  justify-self: end;
  padding-right: 0.3rem;
}

.nested-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
  justify-items: end;
}

.nested-2>div {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 0.2rem;
  padding-right: 0.2rem;
  align-self: end;
}

.nested-3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  /* justify-items: center; */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  color: black;
  background: black;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding: 1rem;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.nested-3>* {
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.operations {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.3rem;
  background-color: orange;
}

.left-cell {
  background: black;
}

.right-cell {
  background: black;
}

.calculator {
  background: #333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-cell">
  </div>

  <div class="calculator">
    <div class="nested-1 top-bar">
      <div class="flight-modus"><img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/sebv9j.png" alt="flight mode"> &nbsp;
        <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/5zqf4k.png" alt="wifi signal at full strength"></div>
      <div>10:10 am</div>
      <div class="charge-status">96% <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/30ldxtx.png" alt="battery at near full charge"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="nested-2 result">
      <div>3,658.8</div>
    </div>

    <div class="nested-3 keys">
      <div class="operations">C</div>
      <div class="operations">+/-</div>
      <div class="operations">%</div>
      <div class="operations">/</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="right-cell">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Column**

```
.nested-3 > div:nth-child(4n) {
  background-color: orange;
}

.nested-3 > div:not(:nth-child(3)):nth-child(4n + 3) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/a13L2rb0/2/)

```css
html {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1.2fr 1fr 1.2fr;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(700px, auto);
}

.wrapper>div {
  padding: 0;
}

.nested-1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  justify-items: center;
}

.nested-1>div {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.6rem;
  color: white;
}

.top-bar {
  padding-top: 0.3rem;
}

.flight-modus {
  justify-self: start;
  padding-left: 0.3rem;
}

.charge-status {
  justify-self: end;
  padding-right: 0.3rem;
}

.nested-2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(200px, auto);
  justify-items: end;
}

.nested-2>div {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 0.2rem;
  padding-right: 0.2rem;
  align-self: end;
}

.nested-3 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  /* justify-items: center; */
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  color: black;
  background: black;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  padding: 1rem;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.nested-3>* {
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.operations {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.3rem;
}

.nested-3>div:nth-child(4n) {
  background-color: orange;
}

.nested-3>div:not(:nth-child(3)):nth-child(4n + 3) {
  background-color: red;
}

.left-cell {
  background: black;
}

.right-cell {
  background: black;
}

.calculator {
  background: #333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-cell">
  </div>

  <div class="calculator">
    <div class="nested-1 top-bar">
      <div class="flight-modus"><img src="http://i63.tinypic.com/sebv9j.png" alt="flight mode"> &nbsp;
        <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/5zqf4k.png" alt="wifi signal at full strength"></div>
      <div>10:10 am</div>
      <div class="charge-status">96% <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/30ldxtx.png" alt="battery at near full charge"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="nested-2 result">
      <div>3,658.8</div>
    </div>

    <div class="nested-3 keys">
      <div class="operations">C</div>
      <div class="operations">+/-</div>
      <div class="operations">%</div>
      <div class="operations">/</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>5</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="right-cell">
  </div>
</div>
```